# When can we use "light"as a countable noun?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

I don't know why some native speakers say that "**I shone light on his face**" is wrong.

They said I had to say "**I shone a light on his face**" or "**I shone the light on his face**".

Answer (score 2):

These are two different meanings of the word "light".

The uncountable noun refers to the general concept of light. "I shone light on his face" means "I caused some beam of light to go onto his face".

But the countable noun refers to *a thing that produces light*; so, a lamp, a torch/flashlight, a candle, etc. "I shone the light on his face" might mean "I moved my flashlight so that its beam went onto his face".